# Sql Query assistance (oracle) - new

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with following columns:
DOCCHECK (skill, usernum, checknum)
SKILL (skill, checknum)

I get input of  usernum and skill
If (input_usernum = DOCCHECK.usernum and DOCCHECK.skill=inputskill) then I return DOCCHECK.checknum
else I return SKILL.checknum where SKILL.skill

Example:

**DOCCHECK**

```
+-------+----------+-----------+
| skill |  usernum |  checknum |
+-------+----------+-----------+
|     1 |      111 |        30 |
|     2 |      222 |        99 |
|     3 |      111 |         4 |
+-------+----------+-----------+
```

**SKILL**

```
+-------+-----------+
| skill |  checknum |
+-------+-----------+
|     1 |         4 |
|     2 |        30 |
|     3 |        50 |
|     4 |         2 |
+-------+-----------+
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
input user: 333, 3 - should return checknum - 50
input user: 222,2 - should return - 99
input user: 222,3 - should return 50
```

Thank you

Comment: And your current code is ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you have a requirement where you want something from a table (in your case `doccheck` only if it exists), you should at least consider an outer join.

So,

```
SELECT    coalesce(dc.checknum, s.checknum)
FROM      skill s
LEFT JOIN doccheck dc ON dc.skill = s.skill AND dc.usernum = :input_usernum
WHERE     s.skill = :input_skill
```

This query will start by finding the `skill` row that matches the user input and then find the `doccheck` row that matches the user input *if it exists*.  If it does not exist, then all the column values returned for `doccheck` will be `null`.  We then use `coalesce` to return the `doccheck.checknum` value if it was found and the `skill.checknum` value otherwise.

Note that in my example `:input_usernum` and `:input_skill` are bind variables to represent your user input.  They could also be `PL/SQL variables:

```
SELECT    coalesce(dc.checknum, s.checknum)
FROM      skill s
LEFT JOIN doccheck dc ON dc.skill = s.skill AND dc.usernum = p_input_usernum
WHERE     s.skill = p_input_skill
```

or they could be literals (though this would be bad for other, unrelated reasons):

```
SELECT    coalesce(dc.checknum, s.checknum)
FROM      skill s
LEFT JOIN doccheck dc ON dc.skill = s.skill AND dc.usernum = 333
WHERE     s.skill = 3
```